# Resource Manager web UI not working

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-2.7.2

I have pasted the configurations below

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration><!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties --><property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value></property><property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value></property><property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>    <value>idea-ind-cie1:8026</value></property><property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>idea-ind-cie1:8031</value></property><property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>idea-ind-cie1:8041</value></property><property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:8088</value></property></configuration>
```

Output of netstat -tupln

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15678/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9743/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35773               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15678/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56165               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15929/java
tcp        0      0 172.24.191.223:54310        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15678/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15929/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:6066  :::*                        LISTEN      19284/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:8089  :::*                        LISTEN      30300/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:8026  :::*                        LISTEN      30300/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:8031  :::*                        LISTEN      30300/java
tcp        0      0 :::8033                     :::*                        LISTEN      30300/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:7077  :::*                        LISTEN      19284/java
tcp        0      0 :::9000                     :::*                        LISTEN      19284/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.24.191.223:8041  :::*                        LISTEN      30300/java
```

Log file of Resource Manager

```
2018-04-18 19:22:43,662 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8088 
2018-04-18 19:22:45,503 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8088 
2018-04-18 19:22:45,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app cluster started at 8088
```

Comment: Look at the `resourcemanager` logs file

Comment: @cricket_007  have pasted the resource manager log file below. I didnt find anything wrong in the log file

Comment: Log file of Resource Manager

2018-04-18 19:22:43,662 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8088

2018-04-18 19:22:45,503 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8088
2018-04-18 19:22:45,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app cluster started at 8088